# Date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, Boolean Given

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function where I want to check between two dates if there is a certain amount of weeks between them.

```
public function checkShifts()
    {
        $now = new DateTime();
        $shifts = Shift::where("disabled", "=", "0")->get();

        foreach ($shifts as $shift)
        {
            $time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:MMM:SS', $shift->start, null);

            if (date_diff($now, $time, false) >= 42)
            {
                $shift->disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the Shift starting date, convert it to a DateTime object and try to run the date_diff. However, I keep on getting the **Date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, Boolean Given** error.

VAR_DUMP:

```
object(App\Shift)#729 (26) {
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(5) "shift"
  ["connection":protected]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["withCount":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(21)
    ["start"]=>
    string(19) "2020-02-03 15:00:00"
    ["end"]=>
    string(19) "2020-02-03 21:00:00"
    ["department_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["disabled"]=>
    int(0)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2020-02-03 15:41:06"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2020-02-03 20:39:27"
```

Comment: Inside your `foreach`, `var_dump($shift)`; to make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: Yes it does contain the shift array that I want to use

Comment: If `$shift` is an array, then you shouldn't be doing `$shift->start`

Comment: Oh I am sorry! I meant one shift entry from the array

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the `var_dump()` for one `$shift`

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat will return false on failure so either your format string is incorrect or $shift->start is incorrect.

Comment: Also, what do you think "H:MMM:SS" represents in the date format?  Because I can pretty much guarantee it's not what you think it is.  See date formatting characters [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Comment: Added the var_dump

Comment: The format that you want is "Y-m-d H:i:s"  Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues) returns false on failure.

Looks to me like `Y-m-d H:MMM:SS` is the incorrect format. `Y-m-d H:i:s` would be `2020-02-03 21:40:20`.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee said, its a wrong format which causes the formatted date to be a boolean...

What you can do is cast the start attribute as datetime inside the model and have something like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'start' => 'datetime',
    ...
];
```

Then you'll be able to do something like this:

```
public function checkShifts()
{
    $shifts = Shift::where("disabled", "=", "0")->get();

    foreach ($shifts as $shift)
    {
        if ($shift->start->diffInWeeks(now()) >= 42)
        {
            $shift->disabled = true;
        }
    }

    return $shifts;
}
```

With collection's map method:

```
public function getShifts()
{
    return Shift::where("disabled", "0")->get()->map(function ($shift) {
        $shift->disabled = (bool)$shift->start->diffInWeeks(now()) >= 42;

        return $shift;
    })->values();
}
```

You can use collection's filter method to get only enabled shifts:

```
public function enabledShifts()
{
    return Shift::where("disabled", "0")->get()->filter(function ($shift) {
        return $shift->start->diffInWeeks(now()) >= 42;
    })->values();
}
```